# Running .net applications on a VPS

Tags: .net, vb.net, vps

It seems like a silly question but, I wanted to know that, if i upload an application to a Virtual Private Server and run it, will it keep running continuously?

I mean that if i put a int increment in a timer and display it in a text box or a label will it keep on the adding up even if i log out of the Virtual Private Server.

The problem is i cannot try it on a VPS as i don't have access to one.

The problem statement is that i have to access an online DB and read from it continuously.

Comment: Yes, the VPS works even if you are not looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A VPS is a server. A virtualized one, but still a server. It is not paused unless someone does that explicitly, or it wouldn't be able to service requests.

The fact it's virtualized is not relevant.

As a side note, if you're using ASP.NET, beware of the application pool recycling mechanism, which will stop your app if there are no requests, and restart it once in a while even if there are requests.

Comment: I am planning to deploy a vb.net desktop application.

Comment: @user2866752 Then the ASP.NET remark is irrevelant to you. Your app will work the same way as on any other computer.